# AngularJS Bootstrap Modal result without closing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement the [m-e-controy Angular-Dialog-Service](https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service) into my AngularJS application. I want to make an "edit" dialog to change values of an object. The app is controlled by the `FactorController`, which opens a dialog, passes the factor to edit and binds the `FactorDialogController` to it.

This works fine. I understand that I can return data to the `FactorController` by shooting `$modalInstance.close(data)`. But this closes the dialog. How do I just return data, keep the dialog, do some validation stuff in the `FactorController`, and when everything's okay, THEN close the dialog? See comments.

```
module.controller('FactorController', ['FactorREST', '$scope', 'dialogs', function($FactorREST, $scope, dialogs) {

    ...

    this.editFactor = function(factor) {
        var dlg = dialogs.create('/js/angularjs/template/custom/factor.html','FactorDialogController',factor, {size: 'md', copy:true});
        dlg.result.then(function(data){
            _this.connectionStatus = _this.STATUS_LOADING;

            $FactorREST.put({id: factor.id}, data).$promise.then(function(response) {
                _this.connectionStatus = _this.STATUS_DONE;
            }).catch(function() {
                _this.connectionStatus = _this.STATUS_DONE;
                connectionErrorDialog();
            });
        });
    };
)

.controller('FactorDialogController',function($scope,$modalInstance,data){

    $scope.tmpFactor = data;

    /* Callbacks**************************************************
    *************************************************************/

    $scope.save = function() {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.tmpFactor);
        // don't close, but something linke $modalInstance.return($scope.tmpFactor)
    };

    $scope.abort = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('Abgebrochen');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is using service. You should put logic in service instead of controller anyway.

Generally speaking, controller is the place for you to wire things with scope.

Other than this should go to factory/service.

Comment: So you mean having some kind of a `FactorService` that is injected into the `FactorDialogController` and then called like
`FactorService.isValid(factor)`?

Comment: Yes. And it will be easier for you to do unit test.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I have a much better understanding of the concept now.